# Magento 2 How to disable admin menu based on configuration?

Tags: magento2, admin, xml, menu

xcz[image]

I want to hide my custom module menu based on configuration. If in configuration it set to "yes" then the menu should display and if set to "no" then menu should not appear at admin.

I have below code for add menu:

```
<menu>
 <add id="Name_Module::parent" title="title" module="Name_Module" sortOrder="51" resource="Name_Module::parent"/>
 <add id="Name_Module::shippinglocation" title="Manage title" module="Name_Module" sortOrder="40" parent="Name_Module::parent" action="controller/action" resource="Name_Module::module"/>
</menu>
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please follow this link to achieve this https://tagvibe.com/magento2/hide-admin-menu-based-on-system-config-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dependsOnConfig="section/group/field"`

Example:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::abcd" title="Title" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="100" resource="Vendor_Module::abcd" dependsOnConfig="section/group/field"/>        
    </menu>
```

Also for the other options too, you can check the xsd mentioned above i.e `Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd`

Comment: thanks, will it be work with store wise? in my code i have two lines of menu on which i need to do use "dependsOnConfig" ?

Comment: Sorry if I am misinterpreting you but the menu is viewed inside the admin panel so how it can be store wise? Please explain the use case?

you can add "dependsOnConfig" in any/all menu(s) in your menu.xml

Comment: To stop module's functionality for particular store is a different thing which needs to put config check inside the logic.